# MySQL Ignore NULL results after first occurrence

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table `lastviewed` in MySQL database,

```
CREATE TABLE `lastviewed` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `record_id` int(11),
  `product_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `lastviewed` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

I need to get last 4 rows `ORDER BY lastviewed DESC LIMIT 4` of this table filtered by current [logged-in] `user_id` and this is not the big deal, But there are some new requirements where I'm stuck

I've following cases.

1. DON'T show the `NULL` `record` row if that `product` already has another row (in the first 4 entries of last viewed. because only the first 4 are shown) with a record (i.e. `record_id` column has a value).
2. Show the `NULL` row only if the `product` does not have another row with a value `record_id` in one of the first 4 rows of the last viewed because only first 4 shown.
3. If there are two, three or four rows for the same `product` and all rows have different `record_id` show all of them.

Currently I've this query

```
SELECT * FROM `lastviewed` WHERE `user_id` = xxx 
ORDER BY `lastviewed` DESC LIMIT 4
```

I know we required some sub queries and IF/ELSE CASE/THEN conditions, but I've NO HINT how to achieve it.

**Sample Data**

```
id      record_id   product_id  user_id     lastviewed  
261766  145304      95650       266         2014-03-14 03:34:16
261594  NULL        95650       266         2014-03-14 02:47:38
261765  145303      91312       266         2014-03-14 01:57:26
261444  NULL        91312       266         2014-03-14 01:44:33
261778  145314      91312       266         2014-03-10 23:02:39
261777  NULL        91312       266         2014-03-10 23:02:13
261776  145313      91312       266         2014-03-10 23:00:26
261775  NULL        91312       266         2014-03-10 22:59:13
261774  NULL        93185       266         2014-03-10 22:57:16
261773  NULL        93185       266         2014-03-10 22:53:47
```

And the **required result**

```
261766  145304      95650       266         2014-03-14 03:34:16
261765  145303      91312       266         2014-03-14 01:57:26
261778  145314      91312       266         2014-03-10 23:02:39
261776  145313      91312       266         2014-03-10 23:00:26
261774  NULL        93185       266         2014-03-10 22:57:16
```

With the `LIMIT 4`

```
261766  145304      95650       266         2014-03-14 03:34:16
261765  145303      91312       266         2014-03-14 01:57:26
261778  145314      91312       266         2014-03-10 23:02:39
261776  145313      91312       266         2014-03-10 23:00:26
```

**Fiddle:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3e20e/2/0

Comment: All your columns are either not null or have a default - how can there ever be nulls? Also, you can have null columns, but not null rows...

Comment: `record_id` is null able and I add null in specific case.

Comment: In that case, it would help to see some sample data, along with the results you expect.

Comment: @NevilleK I've removed the Default from `record_id` to avoid confusions..

Comment: Sure.. wait a moment please..

Comment: @NevilleK please check

Comment: Is that the input data, or the result you're trying to achieve?

Comment: This is the data I received by applying `SELECT * FROM lastviewed WHERE user_id = 266 
ORDER BY lastviewed DESC LIMIT 10`

Comment: @NevilleK Please Check, Now it will help to understand more clearly..

Comment: I made a SQLFiddle for your example. You may include this in your post. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a12c4/2

Comment: Is this what you want? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a12c4/9. Consider playing with it a bit, I'm not sure it cover all your cases.

Comment: Not sure, it is not showing the last null record.. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3e20e/6/0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope it helps and meets your expectations.

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT * FROM `lastviewed` WHERE `user_id` = 266 AND record_id IS NOT NULL 
UNION
SELECT * FROM `lastviewed` WHERE product_id NOT IN
(SELECT product_id FROM `lastviewed` WHERE record_id IS NOT NULL GROUP BY product_id)
) AS q1 
GROUP BY product_id, record_id
ORDER BY `lastviewed` DESC 
LIMIT 4;
```

Comment: Yes It works, Thank you very much, I thought this is not possible with only querying the database and I was thinking to achieve this by applying some programming tricks, but after seeing your query I have changed my mind, thanks once again. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2606d/1